# Got stuck at trying to implement ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java how to: Generic Array creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

I am using tons of ArrayLists in my program that does not need most of the functionality of Java arraylist, so basicly i want to implement it myself to get better space performance.

this is what i got so far:

```
public class ArrayList<E> {
    private E[] a;
    private int size=0;
    public ArrayList() {
    }
    public ArrayList(int fixedSize) {
        ***a=new E[fixedSize];***
    }

}
```

the compiler says i cant create a generic Array, how do i over come this?

Comment: if you really want to create an ArrayList, why not looking over here:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html
This will at least show you, how a proper implementation looks like and what to think of when making your own.

Answer (score 2):

The way we did it back before there were generics. Make an array of `Object`s and cast when taking them out. As you're the only one adding to the array, it *should* be safe, but you can add an `instanceof` check just in case.